# Is the volitional form of i-adjectives often used?

Tags: i-adjectives, volitional-form

According to this [question](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/3301/4216) the volitional form of i-adjectives is used *quite often* -- on a daily basis. But I almost never hear it. I almost see it exclusively in books (or written documents). And if it would be used in a dialogue it would almost always be used by a man.

On the other hand, I hear quite often adj-i+でしょう.

So my question is the ～かろう form that much used?

Comment: I don't agree with the answer you've selected at all. I hear it a lot in anime, but I do not think it's common to hear in real life. I think adj+だろう or でしょう is far more common.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This form is [classified as modern 口語 (as opposed to 文語)](http://www.hello-school.net/harojapa007.htm), but it sounds old-fashioned nevertheless. It's not something we hear every day. We mostly see this form in fictional old person's speech (like in the original question) or in a few fixed expressions like [安かろう悪かろう](http://kotowaza-allguide.com/ya/yasukarouwarukarou.html). よかろう is often used by a pompous, old and/or noble person in fiction. If someone around you used よかろう in reality, it's likely to be a joke.

By the way, is that form really called the "volitional" form while the meaning is ～だろう? It appears similar to 行こう/見よう/食べよう, but the meaning is totally different.

Comment: "If someone around you used よかろう in reality, it's likely to be a joke." That is quite reassuring, thank you. || As I understand, "volitional form" means ～よう. For sure, the よう 助動詞 is not always about volition (as in this question) but it is usually called "volition form" even though.