# Volitional form

Tags: translation, volitional-form, pragmatics

> もう20年にもなろうか。伊勢崎の人で覚えている人があろう。

Is the author doing hypothesis by using the form that I have marked? 
This is the opening sentence of a ghost story which is set in Isezaki.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "volitional" う/よう has several meanings. Here, these なろう and あろう express a **guess** of the speaker (i.e., "it seems ～", "I think ～", "look like ～"). Basically they mean the same thing as もう20年にもなるだろうか and 覚えている人があるだろう, respectively. This usage is uncommon in spoken Japanese, but not rare in literary and stiff sentences. You may have seen [`adjective + かろう`](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/3300/5010) before, which is essentially the same pattern.

As for the second sentence, ある is an old-fashioned and stiff way of saying いる. In archaic Japanese ある was safely used for people (e.g., 人あり in archaic Japanese = 人がいる in modern Japanese). Normally this sentence should be written as 覚えている人がいるだろう or 覚えている人がいよう.

References:

- [What Does the "Volitional" Really Mean?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/36505/5010)
- [Advanced Volitional](http://www.guidetojapanese.org/learn/grammar/volitional2) (see the last section)