# What does かろう　かろう　なんだけどな mean?

Tags: sentence, particle-だけ, no-da

> まあ　ごめんなさい。　この子　安酒の匂いがに苦手で。。。

"Ah, I'm sorry. This child is bad with the smell of cheap sake"

And his answer is

> あ　匂っちゃったか~
> 安かろう美味かろうなんだけどな
> ひっく!

"Ah, it stinks"

What exactly is the meaning かろう+  かろう+ なんだけどな?

Answer (score 3):

安かろう美味かろう is a one-off parody of [安かろう悪かろう](https://jisho.org/word/%E5%AE%89%E3%81%8B%E3%82%8D%E3%81%86%E6%82%AA%E3%81%8B%E3%82%8D%E3%81%86), which is a common set phrase. かろう is an uncommon inferential (or "volitional") form of an i-adjective:

- [よかろう - What does it mean? Where does it come from?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/3300/5010)
- [Is the volitional form of i-adjectives often used?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/44985/5010)

So the literal meaning of 安かろう悪かろう is something like "seemingly cheap, seemingly bad", hence the idiomatic meaning of "you get what you pay for". You won't see this ～かろう～かろう pattern outside of this set phrase, so [you need to learn it by rote](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/42724/5010).

In your case, 安かろう美味かろう is the opposite of 安かろう悪かろう, so the intended meaning as a parody is "This drink tastes great for the price" or "You get more than what you pay for".

～なんだけどな is just "It's ～, isn't it?". 安かろう美味かろう is being treated as a long noun phrase.

Comment: It also seems to me that the speaker insists that the sake tastes better when it's rather cheap...

Comment: @rk03 You mean "The cheaper, the tastier"? That could be a possible interpretation depending on the context. I'm not sure if such a correlation is explicitly stated in this situation, though.